# Google OAuth Always Showing Consent Screen on calling grantOfflineAccess method from gapi

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

In my application, I need refresh token for offline access. For getting authorization code, we are using grantOfflineAccess method of gapi where we get authorization code.Using that code, we will get access token by calling v4/token api.But every time, consent screen  prompt to user. Is their any way so that consent screen will not be prompted at every time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2offlineaccessoptions), no. You need to get consent from the user in a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the access token to [exchange it for a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_7_exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token). To avoid calling this process several times, you should persist this refresh token so you can use it anytime.